# How to send empty arguments in a parametrized pytest test?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am using Pytest. I have a function with several arguments and I am using a parametrized test to check different combinations of those arguments. But I would like to be able to not have all arguments in all test cases. Is there a way that I can indicate in the tuples where I define the test cases that some arguments are empty?

Here is a minimal example. In the case below I would like to have another test wher I pass only the first argument, e.g. 1 and the expected result 5 (1+4).

I have tried (1,,5) and (1,None,5) but none seems to work.

The example below is a very simplified case, I could probably have a separate test function. But in a general case with lots of arguments it would be quite helpful to be able to parametrize the function to test not passing a each argument.

```
import pytest

def foo(arg1, arg2=4):
    return arg1+arg2

@pytest.mark.parametrize("first,second,expected_result",[(1,2,3),(2,3,5)])
def test(first,second,expected_result):
    assert foo(first,second) == expected_result
```

Comment: (I can't test this with `pytest`) I think you want to pass a parameter list to `foo()`: You need your `parametrize` to be like: `@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo_params,expected_result",[((1,2),3),((2,3),5),((3,),7])`, then: `def test(foo_params,expected_result):`, then: `assert foo(*foo_params) == expected_result`

Comment: The fundamental problem is that there is no argument that a call will interpret as "no argument provided". Either use @quamrana's suggestion, or write two separate tests that parameterize on one and two explicit arguments, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "first,second,expected_result", [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5), (1, None, 5)]
)
def test(first, second, expected_result):
    if second is None:
        actual = foo(first)
    else:
        actual = foo(first, second)
    assert actual == expected_result
```

A more generic approach, which can be used to test any function with any number of parameters:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "args,kwargs,expected_result",
    [
        ((1, 2), {}, 3),
        ((2, 3), {}, 5),
        ((1,), {}, 5),
    ],
)
def test(args, kwargs, expected_result):
    actual = foo(*args, **kwargs)
    assert actual == expected_result
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "empty" argument, so there is nothing (except the default value itself, of course) that could substitute `second` in your call:

```py
    foo(first,second)
```

If you want to call your function with a variable number of arguments, but use the same signature, you have to pass the argument list instead:

```py
    foo(*args)
```

This way, you can now parametrize your test with argument lists of different length:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("args,expected_result", [((1, 2), 3), ((1,), 5)])
def test(args, expected_result):
    assert foo(*args) == expected_result
```

This implies that the arguments are called as positional arguments.
For completeness, if for some reason you want to test keyword arguments instead, you can also do that be providing these instead:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("kwargs,expected_result", [({"arg1": 1, "arg2": 2}, 3),
                                                    ({"arg1": 1}, 5)])
def test(kwargs, expected_result):
    assert foo(**kwargs) == expected_result
```